# How to solve difference in character handling between plain r and rmarkdown

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, rstudio, r-markdown

I have a data frame with a variable name that contains the letter ë. I use project text encoding UTF-8. The 'save with encoding' and 'reopen with encoding' have both been set to UTF-8, as well. When I run an r script, e.g. to mutate in my data frame, like:

```
df <- mutate(df, newvar=2*variablë)
```

everything goes well. However, when I embed the same script in an rmarkdown file and render an html_document with it, there is this error:

```
unexpected input
660:     df <- mutate(df, newvar=2*variablÃ«
                                          ^
```

I am almost certain it has something to do with the encoding, but I can't explain why the r script doesn't do its job from within an rmarkdown document while otherwise there doesn't seem to be a problem.

Does anyone have an idea?

*EDIT*

Here's a working example of an Rmd file.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
c1 <- c("test1","test1","test2","test2")
c2 <- c(1,2,3,4)
data_object <- as.data.frame(cbind(c1,c2))
names(data_object) <- c("tëst","test2")

filter(data_object, tëst=="test1")
```
````

When I run the r script in the RStudio console, there is no problem with the exected result:

```
   tëst test2
1 test1     1
2 test1     2
```

but when I render the  .Rmd file with:

```
rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd",c("html_document"))
```

it got this error:

```
processing file: test.Rmd
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
Quitting from lines 7-14 (test.Rmd) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:7:23: unexpected input
6:                              
7: filter(data_object, tÃ«
```

some session information:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
```

I use RStudio version Version 0.99.465

When I open the .Rmd file in RStudio, it gives a warning 'unexpected token' meaning the variable "tëst".
When I put the same piece of R code in an R file, there is no warning.

I really hope there is someone who can help me, it drives me mad.

Comment: Can you add minimal `test.Rmd` example to your post, also mention OS, R, and Rstudio version.

Comment: Hi zx8754 I added an example. I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see any error, maybe [this is relevant](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html)? Must be something to do with Locale, from my sessionInfo: ` LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 `. Please add *sessionInfo()* output to your post.

Comment: I allready added it.  Do you miss anything?

Comment: See [screenshot](http://imgur.com/eEdb4uM), it works fine for me.

Comment: thank you for trying. Did you set alle the encodings to UTF-8 as well? I even tried this: options(datatable.fread.dec.locale="English_United Kingdom.1252"), but with no success.

Comment: I tried with `ISO-8859-1(sys default)` and `UTF-8`, both worked.

Comment: what if you do localeToCharset()? I get `[1] "ISO8859-1"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92148/discussion-between-zx8754-and-user1983395).